# Apex charts: Show Y-axis label and data label value above the bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, apexcharts

I am using ApexCharts to display a horizontal barchart.

I have a design like this:

[image]

So far I've achieved up to here using custom datalabels in apexcharts.

[image]

How can I tweak apexcharts to match my design so that the y-axis label and data labels are above the bar like in my design? Also, can I apply border-radius to all four corners?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    apexchart: VueApexCharts,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      series: [{
        data: [12787, 11903, 4446, 163, 978, 93],
      }, ],
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          type: "bar",
          height: 350,
          toolbar: {
            show: false,
          },
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          offsetY: -14,
          textAnchor: "start",
          formatter: function(val, opt) {
            return opt.w.globals.labels[opt.dataPointIndex] + ": " + val
          }
        },
        fill: {
          colors: ["#E0655D"],
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            barHeight: "15%",
            borderRadius: 4,
            horizontal: true,
            dataLabels: {
              position: "bottom",
            },
            colors: {
              backgroundBarColors: ["#fff"],
              backgroundBarOpacity: 0.5,
              backgroundBarRadius: 4,
            },
          },
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [
            "RCC With Pillar",
            "Cement Bonded Bricks/Stone",
            "Mud Bonded Bricks/Stone",
            "Wooden Pillar",
            "Not Stated",
            "Others"
          ],
          labels: {
            show: false,
          },
          axisBorder: {
            show: false,
          },
          axisTicks: {
            show: false,
          },
        },
        yaxis: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
    };
  },
})
```

```css
.apexcharts-grid {
  display: none;
}

#chart {
  background-color: #252D35;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="chart">
      <apexchart type="bar" height="350" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexchart>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-apexcharts"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/aanish/4os8cuvL/4/

Thanks in advance